# Cassandra query returns empty array on first query but non-empty array on subsequent queries

Tags: database, node.js, asynchronous, cassandra

I am trying to do a simple query against a Cassandra cluster using the Node.js Cassandra driver. I am following the examples, but it seems like my callback functions are getting called even if there are no results in the returned set.

```
var q = function (param) {
    var query = 'SELECT * FROM my_table WHERE my_col=?';
    var params = [param];

    console.log("Cassandra query is being called with parameters " + params);

    client.execute(query, params, function (err, result) {
        console.log("Cassandra callback is being called. Row count is " + result.rows.length);

        if (err != null) {
            console.log("Got error");
        }

        if (result.rows.length <= 0) {
            console.log("Sending empty response.");
        }
        else {
            console.log("Sending non-empty response.");
        }
    });
};

q('value');
q('value');
```

Outputs

```
Cassandra query is being called with parameters value
Cassandra query is being called with parameters value
Cassandra callback is being called. Row count is 0
Sending empty response.
Cassandra callback is being called. Row count is 1
Sending non-empty response.
```

This is happening fairly consistently, but sometimes both calls will come up empty, and sometime both calls will return values.

I guess I'm doing something wrong with the async calls here, but I'm not really sure what it is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this was due to a bad node in my cluster. One of the nodes was missing a bunch of data, and so one third of the time I would get back no results.

Answer (score 0):

When you open the connection do you send down a `consistency` command?

I had this issue as well, when I open a connection call `execute` and send `use <keyspace>;` followed by `consistency local_quorum;`. This tells Cassandra to look a little harder for the answer and agree with other nodes that you are getting the latest version.

Note: I keep my connections around for a while, so this doesn't add any meaningful overhead (for me).

Note2: The above doesn't seem to work from my python app anymore (using Cassandra 3.5). However, using `SimpleStatement` and setting the `consistency` before calling `execute` does: https://datastax.github.io/python-driver/getting_started.html#setting-a-consistency-level

I hope this helps.